# iPad 2 deleted notes - how to find

Tags: icloud

I have a problem with "NOTES" on my iPad. I have missing notes that appear to be deleted. I have been trying to get on to iCloud to see if I can find them ther, but I can't seem to login. I'm going through a divorce & have important notes. It seems like my wife has somehow logged into my iCloud account & deleted them. Is ther a way to find them?

Answer (score 1):

The simply answer is, unfortunately, that it will likely not be possible to recover notes that were deleted through iCloud.

Your only possible way to recover the notes would be if you have Time Machine backup on a OSX computer that is logged into your iCloud account. Honestly, even for this to work would be highly unlikely.

In the future, check out Evernote, or Google Drive to store your important notes.